# Am I doing too many likelihood ratio tests to simplify the model?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, multiple-comparisons, likelihood-ratio, link-function

I am building a GLM model on a large data set. The main variables thought to be relevant are X_1,...,X_7. I think the interactions X_1*X_3 and X_2 *X_4 might be significant, so I'll include them initially.

There's a rub. I am pooling data from 4 different countries that I suspect are roughly similar (there might be some minor differences). I would like to avoid building a separate model on each country separately, for practical reasons. Therefore, I propose (following the suggestion [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/263249/testing-whether-we-should-build-a-model-on-the-union-of-data-sets)) to also include categorical variables for each country: C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4. And I suspect that there might be some interaction between each of these and X_1 perhaps, so I include C_1*X_1,...,C_4*X_1.

I would like to avoid including all of these variables if the interaction terms are in fact meaningless or the categorical country variables have no effect.

The consensus now seems to be (e.g. see Frank Harrell in *Regression Modeling Strategies*) that doing too many comparison tests is dangerous and unjustified. Frank Harrell proposes that one do very limited tests, by for example doing a likelihood ratio test to determine if all the non-linear terms are jointly insignificant. Or a joint test to determine if all interaction terms are jointly insignificant.

I would like to do three likelihood ratio tests in the following order:

1. Test the significance of all the categorical variables (including their interactions).
2. Test the significance of all interaction terms (including those with the categorical variables if they remain after the first test).
3. Test the significance of the [goodness of link](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2346405) term suggested by Pregibon.

**Is this too many tests?**

If this is unjustified, is there a better approach? I don't know how common or desirable a goodness of link test is, but I am trying to be very rigorous and statistically sound.